# Python Tk : How to create a custom message box

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

Please give me advice.

Custom message box requirements include:

1. Be modal (Realized)

   While the message box is displayed, the message box is on the front and other TK objects cannot be operated.
2. Wait for the return value of the message box

   I want to wait for the message box input before moving on to the next action (display / hide widget etc.).
3. I want to continue processing the application(Realized)

   The original Tk object wants to continue regular processing with the after method.
4. I want to adopt my own design(Realized)

   In order to unify the design.

-Execution result-

If you close the message box, an error is displayed.
It will not proceed to the second line in the Btn_Messagebox_clicked method until self.MainWindow_obj is closed.
I don't know why I get an error. Also, if you close the message box, you won't know why it won't come back.

```
invalid command name "2291801753672dialog_mouse_release"
    while executing
"2291801753672dialog_mouse_release 105 1 ?? ?? ?? 264 103442140 ?? 22 6 ?? 0 ?? ?? .!frame3.!button2 5 438 422 ??"
    invoked from within
"if {"[2291801753672dialog_mouse_release 105 1 ?? ?? ?? 264 103442140 ?? 22 6 ?? 0 ?? ?? .!frame3.!button2 5 438 422 ??]" == "break"} break"
    (command bound to event)
```

-code-

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw,ImageFont

class CustomDialog(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.title_bar_color = '#8FAADC'
        self.item_ground_color = 'whitesmoke'
        self.background_color = '#D9D9D9'
        self.select_bar_color = '#BDD7EE'

        self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False
        self.drag_dx = 0
        self.drag_dy = 0
    
    def dialog_left_click(self,event):
        dialog_x=self.dev_dialog.winfo_rootx()
        dialog_y=self.dev_dialog.winfo_rooty()
        point_x=self.dev_dialog.winfo_pointerx()
        point_y=self.dev_dialog.winfo_pointery()

        dx = point_x - dialog_x
        dy = point_y - dialog_y

        if (dx >= 0 and dx <= self.title_bar_width) and (dy >= 0 and dy <= self.title_bar_height):
            self.drag_dx = dx
            self.drag_dy = dy
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = True
        return

    def dialog_mouse_move_on(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            X = event.x_root - self.drag_dx
            Y = event.y_root - self.drag_dy
            self.dev_dialog.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(X, Y))
            pass
        return

    def dialog_mouse_release(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False
        return

class CommonMessageBoxDialog(CustomDialog):
    def __init__(self,title,message,state,parent = None):
        self.return_state = None

        if not isinstance(title,str) or not isinstance(message,str) or not isinstance(state,int):
            return
        if state < 1 or state > 3 :
            return

        root = ttk.tkinter.Tk()

        #root = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        #root.overrideredirect(True)

        super().__init__()
        
        self.box_state = state
        self.box_message = message
        self.box_title = title

        W = 0
        H = 1

        self.dlg_size = [400,200]

        self.title_bar_width = self.dlg_size[W]
        self.title_bar_height = 40

        self.btn_bar_height = 42

        self.btn_32x32_size = 42

        self.row_height = 28
        self.btn_row_height = 32

        self.frm_space = 10

        self.parent = parent
        self.CreateDialog(root)

        root.wait_window(root)
        #root.mainloop()
    
    def CreateDialog(self,root):

        W = 0
        H = 1

        if self.parent != None:
            self.parent.update_idletasks()
            ww=self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
            wh=self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
            x=self.parent.winfo_rootx()
            y=self.parent.winfo_rooty()

            parent_w = self.parent.winfo_width()
            parent_h = self.parent.winfo_height()
            parent_x = self.parent.winfo_x()
            parent_y = self.parent.winfo_y()
        else:
            root.update_idletasks()
            ww=root.winfo_screenwidth()
            wh=root.winfo_screenheight()
            x=root.winfo_rootx()
            y=root.winfo_rooty()

            parent_w = root.winfo_width()
            parent_h = root.winfo_height()
            parent_x = root.winfo_x()
            parent_y = root.winfo_y()


        self.dev_dialog = root
        dialog = self.dev_dialog
        dialog.overrideredirect(True)

        dlg_x = int((parent_x+parent_w) - (self.dlg_size[W]/2))
        dlg_y = int((parent_y+parent_h) - (self.dlg_size[H]/2))

        if dlg_x < 0 : dlg_x = 0 
        if dlg_y < 0 : dlg_y = 0 

        dialog.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(self.dlg_size[W],self.dlg_size[H],dlg_x,dlg_y))


        self.Title_Bar = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.title_bar_color ,
            )
        self.Title_Label = tk.Label(
            self.Title_Bar,
            bg = self.title_bar_color ,
            text = self.box_title,
        )

        dialog.bind('<Button-1>', self.dialog_left_click)
        dialog.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.dialog_mouse_move_on)
        dialog.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.dialog_mouse_release)

        self.MsgArea_frame = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.select_bar_color,
            )
        self.message_frame = tk.Frame(
            self.MsgArea_frame,
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.item_ground_color ,
            )
        self.label_message = tk.Label(
            self.message_frame,
            bg = self.item_ground_color ,
            text = self.box_message,
        )

        self.BtnArea_frame = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            )
            
        self.btn_ok = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'OK',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(1),
            )
            
        self.btn_yes = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'YES',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(1),
            )
            
        self.btn_no = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'NO',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(2),
            )
            
        self.btn_cancel = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'CANCEL',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(3),
            )
                
        frm_space = self.frm_space
        msg_frm_w = 4
        btn_fram_h = 36

        message_area_h = self.dlg_size[H] - self.title_bar_height - frm_space *2 - btn_fram_h

        # Frame
        self.Title_Bar.place(
            x = 0, y = 0, 
            width = self.title_bar_width, height = self.title_bar_height
            )
        self.MsgArea_frame.place(
            x = frm_space, y = self.title_bar_height + frm_space, 
            width = self.title_bar_width - frm_space*2, height = message_area_h
            )
        self.BtnArea_frame.place(
            x = 0, y = self.title_bar_height + frm_space + message_area_h, 
            width = self.title_bar_width, height = btn_fram_h
            )
        
        self.Title_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.Title_Bar.columnconfigure(0,minsize = self.frm_space)
        self.Title_Bar.rowconfigure(0,minsize = self.title_bar_height)
        
        self.MsgArea_frame.columnconfigure(0,minsize = self.frm_space)
        self.MsgArea_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize = message_area_h)
        
        self.BtnArea_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize = btn_fram_h)

        self.message_frame.place(
            x = msg_frm_w, y = msg_frm_w,
            width = self.title_bar_width - frm_space*2 - msg_frm_w*2, height = message_area_h - msg_frm_w*2,
            )

        # self.message_frame
        self.label_message.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)

        if self.box_state == 1:
            self.btn_ok.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - 80/2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
        if self.box_state == 2:
            self.btn_yes.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - (80 + frm_space) , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_no.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) + frm_space , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
        if self.box_state == 3:
            self.btn_yes.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - (80*1.5 + frm_space*2) , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_no.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - 80/2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_cancel.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) + 80/2 + frm_space*2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            

        #dialog.grab_set()
        dialog.grab_set_global()

    def btn_msgbox_clicked(self,state):
        self.return_state = state
        self.dev_dialog.grab_release()
        self.dev_dialog.destroy()

    def get_return_state(self):
        return self.return_state

class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        W = 0
        H = 1
        self.dlg_size = [400,200]

        geo_string = '{}x{}'.format(self.dlg_size[W],self.dlg_size[H])

        self.MainWindow_obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk()
        self.MainWindow_obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        self.CntSting = tk.StringVar()
        self.CntSting.set('...')

        Label_Conter_text = tk.Label(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            textvariable = self.CntSting,
        )

        self.MsgSting = tk.StringVar()
        self.MsgSting.set(str(self.cnt))

        Label_Message_text = tk.Label(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            textvariable = self.MsgSting,
        )

        Btn_Messagebox = tk.Button(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            text = 'Push',
            command = self.Btn_Messagebox_clicked
        )
        Label_Conter_text.pack()
        Label_Message_text.pack()
        Btn_Messagebox.pack()

        self.MainWindow_obj.after(1000,self.loop_msg)

        self.MainWindow_obj.mainloop()

    def Btn_Messagebox_clicked(self):
        self.dlg = CommonMessageBoxDialog(title='Test',message='Do you remember ?',state=3,parent =self.MainWindow_obj)        
        ret = self.dlg.get_return_state()

        if ret == 1:
            self.MsgSting.set('Yes')
        if ret == 2:
            self.MsgSting.set('No')
        if ret == 3:
            self.MsgSting.set('Cancel')
        
        return

    def loop_msg(self):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.MsgSting.set(str(self.cnt))

        self.MainWindow_obj.after(1000,self.loop_msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()
```

Comment: The error location is where the self.MainWindow_obj.after method is called in the loop_msg method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

I'm binding mouse events for custom dialog navigation.
Therefore, after Destroy was called, the dialog with the mouse release event discarded was notified and an error occurred.

To solve this, I made self.isDestroy, and in the btn_msgbox_clicked method, changed self.isDestroy to True and connected the dialog_mouse_release method to the destroy method.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw,ImageFont

import datetime

class CustomDialog(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.title_bar_color = '#8FAADC'
        self.item_ground_color = 'whitesmoke'
        self.background_color = '#D9D9D9'
        self.select_bar_color = '#BDD7EE'

        self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False
        self.drag_dx = 0
        self.drag_dy = 0

    def dialog_left_click(self,event):
        dialog_x=self.dev_dialog.winfo_rootx()
        dialog_y=self.dev_dialog.winfo_rooty()
        point_x=self.dev_dialog.winfo_pointerx()
        point_y=self.dev_dialog.winfo_pointery()

        dx = point_x - dialog_x
        dy = point_y - dialog_y

        if (dx >= 0 and dx <= self.title_bar_width) and (dy >= 0 and dy <= self.title_bar_height):
            self.drag_dx = dx
            self.drag_dy = dy
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = True
        return

    def dialog_mouse_move_on(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            X = event.x_root - self.drag_dx
            Y = event.y_root - self.drag_dy
            self.dev_dialog.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(X, Y))
            pass
        return

    def dialog_mouse_release(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False
        return

class CommonMessageBoxDialog(CustomDialog):
    def __init__(self,title,message,state,parent = None):
        self.return_state = None
        self.isDestroy = False

        if not isinstance(title,str) or not isinstance(message,str) or not isinstance(state,int):
            return
        if state < 1 or state > 3 :
            return

        root = ttk.tkinter.Tk()

        #root = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        #root.overrideredirect(True)

        super().__init__()

        self.box_state = state
        self.box_message = message
        self.box_title = title

        W = 0
        H = 1

        self.dlg_size = [400,200]

        self.title_bar_width = self.dlg_size[W]
        self.title_bar_height = 40

        self.btn_bar_height = 42

        self.btn_32x32_size = 42

        self.row_height = 28
        self.btn_row_height = 32

        self.frm_space = 10

        self.parent = parent
        self.CreateDialog(root)

        root.wait_window(root)

        #root.mainloop()

    def CreateDialog(self,root):

        W = 0
        H = 1

        if self.parent != None:
            self.parent.update_idletasks()
            ww=self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
            wh=self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
            x=self.parent.winfo_rootx()
            y=self.parent.winfo_rooty()

            parent_w = self.parent.winfo_width()
            parent_h = self.parent.winfo_height()
            parent_x = self.parent.winfo_x()
            parent_y = self.parent.winfo_y()
        else:
            root.update_idletasks()
            ww=root.winfo_screenwidth()
            wh=root.winfo_screenheight()
            x=root.winfo_rootx()
            y=root.winfo_rooty()

            parent_w = root.winfo_width()
            parent_h = root.winfo_height()
            parent_x = root.winfo_x()
            parent_y = root.winfo_y()


        self.dev_dialog = root
        dialog = self.dev_dialog
        dialog.overrideredirect(True)

        dlg_x = int((parent_x+parent_w) - (self.dlg_size[W]/2))
        dlg_y = int((parent_y+parent_h) - (self.dlg_size[H]/2))

        if dlg_x < 0 : dlg_x = 0 
        if dlg_y < 0 : dlg_y = 0 

        dialog.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(self.dlg_size[W],self.dlg_size[H],dlg_x,dlg_y))


        self.Title_Bar = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.title_bar_color ,
            )
        self.Title_Label = tk.Label(
            self.Title_Bar,
            bg = self.title_bar_color ,
            text = self.box_title,
        )

        dialog.bind('<Button-1>', self.dialog_left_click)
        dialog.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.dialog_mouse_move_on)
        dialog.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.dialog_mouse_release)

        self.MsgArea_frame = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.select_bar_color,
            )
        self.message_frame = tk.Frame(
            self.MsgArea_frame,
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.item_ground_color ,
            )
        self.label_message = tk.Label(
            self.message_frame,
            bg = self.item_ground_color ,
            text = self.box_message,
        )

        self.BtnArea_frame = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            )

        self.btn_ok = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'OK',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(1),
            )

        self.btn_yes = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'YES',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(1),
            )

        self.btn_no = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'NO',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(2),
            )

        self.btn_cancel = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'CANCEL',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(3),
            )

        frm_space = self.frm_space
        msg_frm_w = 4
        btn_fram_h = 36

        message_area_h = self.dlg_size[H] - self.title_bar_height - frm_space *2 - btn_fram_h

        # Frame
        self.Title_Bar.place(
            x = 0, y = 0, 
            width = self.title_bar_width, height = self.title_bar_height
            )
        self.MsgArea_frame.place(
            x = frm_space, y = self.title_bar_height + frm_space, 
            width = self.title_bar_width - frm_space*2, height = message_area_h
            )
        self.BtnArea_frame.place(
            x = 0, y = self.title_bar_height + frm_space + message_area_h, 
            width = self.title_bar_width, height = btn_fram_h
            )

        self.Title_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.Title_Bar.columnconfigure(0,minsize = self.frm_space)
        self.Title_Bar.rowconfigure(0,minsize = self.title_bar_height)

        self.MsgArea_frame.columnconfigure(0,minsize = self.frm_space)
        self.MsgArea_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize = message_area_h)

        self.BtnArea_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize = btn_fram_h)

        self.message_frame.place(
            x = msg_frm_w, y = msg_frm_w,
            width = self.title_bar_width - frm_space*2 - msg_frm_w*2, height = message_area_h - msg_frm_w*2,
            )

        # self.message_frame
        self.label_message.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)

        if self.box_state == 1:
            self.btn_ok.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - 80/2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
        if self.box_state == 2:
            self.btn_yes.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - (80 + frm_space) , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_no.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) + frm_space , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
        if self.box_state == 3:
            self.btn_yes.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - (80*1.5 + frm_space*2) , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_no.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - 80/2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_cancel.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) + 80/2 + frm_space*2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            

        #dialog.grab_set()
        dialog.grab_set_global()

    def btn_msgbox_clicked(self,state):
        self.return_state = state
        self.isDestroy = True

    def get_return_state(self):
        return self.return_state

    def dialog_mouse_release(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False

        if self.isDestroy:
            self._quit()
        return

    def _quit(self):
        self.dev_dialog.grab_release()
        self.dev_dialog.destroy()


class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        W = 0
        H = 1
        self.dlg_size = [400,200]

        geo_string = '{}x{}'.format(self.dlg_size[W],self.dlg_size[H])

        self.MainWindow_obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk()
        self.MainWindow_obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        self.CntSting = tk.StringVar()
        self.CntSting.set(str(self.cnt))

        Label_Conter_text = tk.Label(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            textvariable = self.CntSting,
        )

        self.MsgSting = tk.StringVar()
        self.MsgSting.set('...')

        Label_Message_text = tk.Label(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            textvariable = self.MsgSting,
        )

        Btn_Messagebox = tk.Button(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            text = 'Push',
            command = self.Btn_Messagebox_clicked
        )
        Label_Conter_text.pack()
        Label_Message_text.pack()
        Btn_Messagebox.pack()

        self.MainWindow_obj.after(1000,self.loop_msg)

        self.MainWindow_obj.mainloop()

    def Btn_Messagebox_clicked(self):
        self.dlg = CommonMessageBoxDialog(title='Test',message='Do you remember ?',state=3,parent =self.MainWindow_obj)        
        ret = self.dlg.get_return_state()

        if ret == 1:
            self.MsgSting.set('Yes')
        if ret == 2:
            self.MsgSting.set('No')
        if ret == 3:
            self.MsgSting.set('Cancel')

        return

    def loop_msg(self):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.CntSting.set(str(self.cnt))

        self.MainWindow_obj.after(1000,self.loop_msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()
```